# Unable to create Singleton

Tags: swift, swift2, singleton

i want to make contact book to i made a class of contact.

there is no compile error but when i run the init i do not get to the "init"pass stage.

what can be the problem ?

here is my code:

```
import UIKit

public class contact {

    var originalNumber: String = ""
    var e164Number: String = ""
    var contactImage: String = ""
    var name: String = ""

    init (originalNumber: String, name: String) {
        self.originalNumber = originalNumber
        self.name = name


    }


}
```

then in my contactDataClass i made:

```
import UIKit

import AddressBook // imports the framework

class contactsDataClass {

    var adbk : ABAddressBook!
    var localContacts = [contact]()

    init() {
        print("get to init")      
        contactsDataClass.sharedInstance.localContacts.append(contact(originalNumber: "0525222022", name: "try appent"))
        print("init pass")    

    } 

    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
        static var instance : contactsDataClass? = nil
    }

    class var sharedInstance : contactsDataClass {
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken){
            Static.instance = contactsDataClass()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }      

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have created infinite recursion

Infact this block

```
class var sharedInstance : contactsDataClass {
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken){
        Static.instance = contactsDataClass()
    }
    return Static.instance!
}
```

calls this

```
init() {
    print("get to init")
    contactsDataClass.sharedInstance.localContacts.append(contact(originalNumber: "0525222022", name: "try appent"))
    print("init pass")    
}
```

which again calls the first block...

### Let's clean up your code

```
public class Contact {
    var originalNumber: String
    var e164Number = ""
    var contactImage = ""
    var name: String

    init (originalNumber: String, name: String) {
        self.originalNumber = originalNumber
        self.name = name
    }
}

class ContactManager {
    static let sharedInstance = ContactManager()
    private init() {}
    var adbk : ABAddressBook! // this is dangerous...
    var contacts = [Contact]()
}
```

> As you can see defining a Singleton class in Swift is much easier than in Objective-C.
>
> You just need to hide the default `initializer` and create the `static` constant `sharedInstance` as shown above.

### Usage

```
ContactManager.sharedInstance.contacts.append(Contact(originalNumber: "0525222022", name: "Test name"))

print(ContactManager.sharedInstance.contacts[0].name) // "Test name"
```

Comment: tnx but i get the same result. its write twice "get to init" and stuck.

Comment: why it write twice "get to init"

Comment: @NirTzin: I totally removed the text "get to init", how is it possible? Please use my code.

Comment: i added it just for test

Comment: @NirTzin: Please show me the code you are using now. I suspect you changed more code...

Comment: hi, today i open a new project and copt the code and it 100% fine :) maybe some old code makes a mess in the old project. tnx a lot :)

Comment: why the ABAddressBook in dangerous? the base idea was to put all contact from the dvice to my own singleton array. can you refere me to good article here in stackoverflow ?